# Git pull and Git clone using REST API

Tags: git, rest

I want to execute git pull and git clone command via REST API. I have searched the api doc but not able to found anything useful.
https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: What does it even mean to clone a repository via a REST api? What format are you expected to get back? Why not simply use `git` itself?

Comment: I want to do it using REST API only. It can be on any format.

Comment: That's not what the GitHub REST API is for. If you want to run git commands on a repository, use a git client.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the repo as zip or tar from archive url.

```
Eg : https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref
```

Archive_format can be zipball or tarball.
Ref is the branch name, by default api will take master branch.

Then from this url, you can download the repo

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
try( ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream()) )
{
    try( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepathToSave) )
    {
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a git repository and then be able to do `git add`, `git commit` or any other `git` command, use `git clone`.

If you just want to get the repository content, you can download an archive with the link https://github.com/{OWNER}/{REPOSITORY}/archive/{BRANCH_NAME}.(zip|tar.gz), (e.g. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/archive/devel.tar.gz).
**But** you won't be able to do any git interaction then...

Comment: I have already tried this API and as you said I was not able to interact with it.

Comment: No, this way you can only get the repository content, not the repository itself. To get the repository, you cannot do it without a git client.

Comment: If you want to create your own client, here are some info on how it works: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

Comment: This is incorrect, you can use the API for creating commits, not only through `git add` / `git commit`. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#create-a-commit

Comment: Right, it's now possible with the "git database" REST API, but I think this API didn't exist at the time of the answer 4 years ago.